# How do I hide information in my JSON response?

Tags: java, json, jackson, javax.xml

Let's say I have a Player class: (ignore access modifiers)

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
class Player {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String secret;
}
```

I also might have castles around the kingdom

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
class Kingdom {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Player owner;
}
```

Now, when I spit the kingdom object to json for consumption by the UI, the player object goes with it, too. This is good, it wouldn't be as useful if you couldn't tell if it was friendly or enemy. But what's bad is that the secret variable is also released. Is it possible to annotate my secret variable to prevent it from being marshaled?

Comment: Do you mean `transient`?

Comment: Well, I still want it to be in the database, so whatever solution would require Hibernate to be able to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can annotate your field or getter with

```
@JsonIgnore
```

The javadoc states

> Marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field is
>   to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization
>   functionality. That is, it should not be consider a "getter", "setter"
>   or "creator".

Comment: This is working exactly as required. I really didn't want to write a custom marshaler, because of all the maintenance involved. Thank you very much.,